# C# Comparing lists using Except

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, list

I've tried searching for the answer on the many other questions but they either don't seem to be relevant or I'm just not knowledgeable enough to know that they are.

My problems is comparing two lists (one of twitter followers the of friends(or who you follow))

This is the code I'm using to gather the lists

```
var friends = user.GetFriends(500).ToList();
var following = user.GetFollowers(500).ToList();
var result = compareFollowingtoFollowers(friends, following);

foreach(var res in result)
{
    lstFollowerChecker.Items.Add(res.ScreenName);
}
```

And this is my compareFollowingtoFollowers function

```
private List<T> compareFollowingtoFollowers<T>(List<T> friends, List<T> followers)
{
    var results = followers.Except(friends).ToList();
    return results;
}
```

**My Problem is it doesn't return what I expect, for example if I ran this against my own account where I say 100 friends and I'm following 112 people, It should return the 12 people that are not following but instead it just seems to return them all.**

Am I using the correct function? The other questions I've read lead me to believe so.

Thank you for reading

Bryan

**UPDATE**

The answers given have been enough to get the cogs in my head ticking again, while the answers are still slightly over my head, I think they were just what I needed to better understand *why* it was returning what it did, Thank you all.

Comment: Are your friends and followers disjoint? If not, then 112 followers minus 100 friends can result in 112 distinct items...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a custom comparer to compare your objects and pass that in the `.Except` method as a second parameter. For example

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class UserComparer : IEqualityComparer<User>
{
    public bool Equals(User x, User y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(User obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the correct function, but your user class does not implement `IEquatable<UserClass>`. This means that `Except` uses reference semantics to compare two users, and since they seem to be different objects (even if "equal") they compare unequal. So it thinks that there is no overlap at all between the two lists.

The solution is to properly implement `IEquatable<T>` to give the class your desired equality semantics (how to do this exactly depends on the properties of that class).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
var result = myFriends.Select(x => yourFriends.All(y => y != x));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely you need to specify how to make comparisons of your types.

According to MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx

Custom types need to implement equals and gethashcode for comparison to be made.